# Need to visualize various sized tables and charts in printed document

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I do have a C# application that calculates storage space in terms of boxes, for some products which itself consist of several parts.

The calculation includes suggestions on how many single parts to put into one box, taking in account volume and weight of the part. The overall result states the number of boxes needed for a given quantity of products.

As of now I am putting the results into a database and then copy it into an Excel file. Furthermore I am creating some charts to better visualize the numbers.

I am not satisfied with this solution. I do however have no idea, on how to programmatically produce a printing output. I am familiar with standard printing in C#, but woking with various sized tables and charts there just seems wrong and an awful lot of work to me.

I have to admit I am lacking some experience in this field, therefore I would be pleased to hear from you on this matter.

Comment: could you post what you have now? we could not even visualize what you can. appreciated if you could post some class/data structures too and some guidelines for expected output.

Comment: I am not sure what class structures I should post. As mentioned, I do not have methods for printing, the only output process I have is writing data into a database. Then I open the database table in SQL Management Studio and copy the values into the Excel file.
In Excel I put the values into a table which is on top of a landscape oriented page, below are some charts. The page layout is repeated for every product. So if there are seven products, my Excel file has seven sheets with always a table and some charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, it is going to take a good amount of work.  I think the most important step towards coming up with a solution is stepping back and realizing everything that needs to be printed and how you would handle it if you were a printer (sounds weird, I know!).

You're going to want to write your own `DocumentPaginator` and draw elements for each page in the overriden `DocumentPaginator.GetPage` method.  The `DocumentPaginator` is what the printer uses to print documents, so it calls the `GetPage` method and you can send it a `DocumentPage` with user controls drawn on it. You also have to be able to do things like calculate how many pages to print, so keep that in mind.

Since they are different sizes you have a couple options that I can think of:

1. Only draw (scale) the tables/charts to be the width of the maximum size of the page being printed
2. Draw 1 visual per page (I would suggest keeping them all landscape or all portrait oriented to keep it simpler for now)

Basically if you're going to use the `PrintDialog`'s dialog for the user to select the printer and printer preferences, it'll save you some work.  If you don't want to show a dialog, then you will need to become fimiliar with `PrintDialog`, `PrintQueue`, `XpsDocumentWriter`, `PrintTicket`, `PrinterCapabilities`, `PrintServer`, and `DocumentPaginator`.

Note: If you allow a users to print 1 control across multiple pages, realize that providing "half drawn" controls and/or printing both "vertically" and "horizontally" adds another degree of complexity.

Comment: It seems I am going to have a look at the DocumentPaginator then. Thank You!